# MySQL move random row from one table to another

Tags: php, mysql, random

Is it possible to move a random row(with one column) to another table in that way so no one get this data even if will request it simultaneously?

For example: If you open my page, you get a data from MySQL that no one will get even if open this page simultaneously with you.

Now I do it this way:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `ShowRow` SELECT * FROM `AllRows` WHERE 1 LIMIT 1");
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `AllRows` LIMIT 1");
```

Is it possible to do some another better way? Or how to `SELECT`some specific row if there is only one column?

Comment: why, you concerned about your database being compromised? what's the reason for it?

Comment: ^or a trigger. Anyway, why bother use WHERE clause if it does just a column exists?

Comment: There is no guarantee to achieve what you are trying even with random selection using `rand` function unless every shown item is stored in a different table so that the next select can cross check if its currently being shown someone else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to all, but I have come up to do it this way:

```
$accCount = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM AllRows");
$accCount = mysqli_num_rows($accCount);
$RandAcc = rand(0, $accCount);
$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `AllRows`");
$ReplaceRandAcc = mysqli_result($result, $RandAcc);

mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `ShowRow` SELECT * FROM `AllRows` WHERE login='".$ReplaceRandAcc."'");
mysqli_query($connect, "DELETE FROM `AllRows` WHERE login='".$ReplaceRandAcc."'");

function mysqli_result($res, $row, $field=0) {
    $res->data_seek($row);
    $datarow = $res->fetch_array();
    return $datarow[$field];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function RAND() to order rows randomly and take the first.

SELECT * FROM AllRows ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1, 1

Comment: That link you left http://sql.sh/fonctions/rand - Not everyone can understand the French language. Stack is mostly an English-based site.